# How to deal with abstract classes and implementations in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, class, abstract

This is my first question here, so please be lenient.

I searched the web and Stackoverflow, but couldn't find anything close to an answer.

I have to dig into someone's code consisting of many abstract classes (extending others) and concrete classes implementing those. It's quite hard to understand what's going on if you have to jump to the abstract class (and the next) forth and back.

I wonder if there's a hidden feature/plugin for Eclipse that makes the implementation details of the abstract class visible in the concrete class, which usually only holds the implementation of the abstract methods. Having an "effective" view in the concrete class would ease the pain to understand the dungle of abstract classes hiding important details.

Looking forward to your answers. :)

Torsten

Comment: *Which* implementation? There can be multiple...

Answer (score 0):

You can type ctrl-O to see the members (fields and methods) of the class, and if you type ctrl-O a second time it will show all the inherited fields and methods.